# Multiple workers on machine - Memory management ( Resque - Rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, memory-management, linux-kernel, resque

We've migrated our Resque background workers from a ton of individual instances on Heroku to between four and ten m4.2xl (32GB Mem) instances on EC2, which is much cheaper and faster.

A few things I've noticed are that: The Heroku instances we were using had 1GB of RAM and rarely ran out of memory. I am currently allocating 24 workers to one machine, so about 1.3GB of memory per worker. However, because the processing power on these machines is so much greater, I think the OS has trouble reclaiming the memory fast enough and each worker ends of consuming more on average. Most of the day the system has 17-20GB memory free but when the memory intensive jobs are run, all 24 workers grab a job almost at the same time and then start growing. They get through a few jobs but then the system hasn't had time to reap memory and crashes if there is no intervention.

I've written a daemon to pause the workers before a crash and wait for the OS to free memory. I could reduce the number of workers per machine overall or have half of them unsubscribe from the problematic queues, I just feel there must be a better way to manage this. I would prefer to be making usage of more than 20% of memory 99% of the day.

The workers are setup to fork a process when they pick up a job from the queue. The master-worker processes are run as services managed with Upstart. I'm aware there are a number of managers which simply restart the process when it consumes a certain amount of memory such as God and Monit. That seems like a heavy handed solution which will end with too many jobs killed under normal circumstances.

Is there a better strategy I can use to get higher utilization with a lowered risk of running into Errno::ENOMEM?

System specs:

OS       :    Ubuntu 12.04
Instance :    m4.2xlarge
Memory   :    32 GB

Comment: Your Resque process should absolutely be under a process monitor of some sort; they can be configured to handle OOM in various ways, including graceful restarts and shutdowns to avoid crashes or lost jobs. Also, and this isn't an answer, so just as a comment, have you looked into migrating to Sidekiq?